# Handcoding Windows GUI in C++ without IDE

Tags: c++, windows, user-interface, notepad++

Hey, I've seen some questions on this topic but most of them only try to point out if its better to or not to use an IDE for creating a GUI, well thats not my question.

I want to use some IDE like Qt for writing bigger programs in the future, but at the moment i am new to c++ and especially GUIs, and want to learn how to handcode simple applications (eg "Hello World"-app with a button, maybe a textbox and a function to spit out a result).
Maybe to prevent discussion about why i want to do this: its because i like to torture myself, and especially because i hate if something (in this case the IDE) creates something i don't understand but nevertheless i have to work with it.

So, are there any tutorials on that topic that gives a short introduction in handcoding small c++ apps with an editor like notepad++?

Comment: So you want to torture yourself. But what GUI framework/library would you like to target? Qt (just the library, not the designer), wxWindows, MFC, or even the Win32 API directly? The latter would be the most masochistic.

Comment: You should tell whether you plan to invoke WinAPI directly (the most painful way - but also the most flexible one) or you want to use an abstraction of it.
A common abstraction is MFC (but as far as I know you need at least the Professional version of Visual Studio to use it).
An alternative (for example used by Google Chrome) is WTL (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Template_Library).
There are other GUI toolkits (often platform-independent) as Qt (its GUI part), wxWidgets, FLTK etc. that abstract even more away.

Comment: i am not sure (as i said, bloody beginner) but yeah it seems that the WinAPI thing is the best way to start. i'll check out that tutorial stakx posted tonight or tomorrow (no time this evening, cinema :) ) and give the "vote ups" and "answer accepts" tonight, as you see i am new to stackoverflow :) hope all that helped accept a written thank you for now, so thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a tutorial for creating a GUI that doesn't require any library, as it targets the native Windows API:

> **Creating Win32-Based Applications (C++)**:
>   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384843.aspx

(As user Nubok wrote in a comment above, programming against the Win32 API is quite strenuous. But you will learn a lot about how Windows works internally.)

This tutorial assumes that you're working with Visual Studio; just ignore the bits where it talks about creating new solutions based on templates etc. That important bits in that article are the code examples.

When it comes to compiling and linking your code, you will need to check with your compiler's manual how exactly to reference external libraries etc. Just make sure that you include the Win32 API's import library in the linking process. (Look out for something called `win32.lib`, `win32api.lib` or similar.)

Answer (score 7):

If you want to learn Win32 I (like many others) recommend Charles Peztold's book:

http://www.charlespetzold.com/pw5/index.html

Unless it has changed since the edition I have, it does not assume any kind of IDE or framework beyond Win32 itself and a C compiler. It will give you a great foundation in how the OS/API works and make it easy to understand the tools and frameworks built on top of it (should you decide to use them).

Comment: thanks for your answer, i think a book is too much for me, i only want to get a basic knowledge of programming GUIs before switching to an IDE.

Comment: Your choice, but a solid foundation will help you even if you switch to using frameworks etc.. It's really useful to understand what things like MFC are doing and why, since they make things appear very different to how they are. (For a large project, MFC is an obfuscation layer as much as, or maybe more than, it is a help to the programmer. :)) Everything in Pezthold remains relevant no matter how you are programming Windows; some tools just let you take shortcuts.

Answer (score 3):

There is a great but dated tutorial covering the plain Windows GUI APIs at [winprog.org](http://winprog.org/tutorial/start.html). It uses plain C though, not C++.

Comment: thanks for your answer, i'd give you a vote up but i cannot yet :) c isnt exactly what i am looking for especially because i can't even tell the difference between c and c++ but i think it teaches some basic understanding aswell